# Can't play video on FireFox and IE

Tags: macos, internet-explorer, firefox, playing

I tried searching for a solution to this and within three days of browsing the forum I could't find any help.

This is the link where I have my video:
http://www.aguacatesjbr.com/English/Company/company.html

I believe the code is correct because I replaced my [source video](http://www.aguacatesjbr.com/Videos/JBR_video.mp4) with the Oceans-Clip video provided by the site. The Oceas-Clip video CAN PLAY on FireFox and IE but not my original video. However, if I type in directly the address of my video it DOES render on FF and IE.

I don´t think it is size problem because I was testing it with a video that weights 4.20MB.

I am having this problem with IE and FireFox in both PC and MAC. Android and Apple devices work perfectly as well with Chrome and Safari.

Comment: This is the link of my source video:
http://www.aguacatesjbr.com/Videos/JBR_video.mp4

This is the link of my light video (4.20MB):
http://www.aguacatesjbr.com/Videos/JBR_mini.mp4

This is the link of the Oceans-Clip video:
http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to serve the videos with the correct mime type, which is `video/mp4` for H.264 in mp4, and `video/webm` for WEBM. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Server_support).

Right now you serve the `.mp4`video as `video/mpeg`.

Then, I your page has a source for `video/webm` pointing to `http://www.aguacatesjbr.com/Videos/JBR_video.webm`, which does not exist at the time of writing. Fix that.

Firefox can play back H.264/mp4 on certain platforms only. For a list of currently supported platforms and video support in Firefox in general see "[Supported media formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility)".

Lastly, there will be warning messages regarding video load failures in newer Firefox versions. E.g.:

```
[20:35:11.515] HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource http://www.aguacatesjbr.com/Videos/JBR_video.mp4 failed. @ http://www.aguacatesjbr.com/English/Company/company.html
[20:35:11.515] All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused. @ http://www.aguacatesjbr.com/English/Company/company.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am not very technical and did't know what or how to add MIME types. the .webm video always existed but could't be play beacause it didn't have the mime. For other people like me that don't know about Mimes, here is a tut: [link](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6286/modifying-or-adding-custom-mime-types-to-windows-hosting-accounts)[/link] which makes me wonder, how did you know that I had the incorrect tag for .mp4? I mean, where or how do you see this things? THANKS A LOT!

Comment: See the linked documentation and/or consult the documentation of your webserver/CDN.

Comment: how do you do that? As I said before I am not really technical on these things, could you provide a step by step? I al ready login to my server I don't see anything, what should I be exactly looking for? thanks in advance, you have been very helpful.

Comment: No, I cannot provide step-by-step. I don't have any idea what server software you're running in what configuration. And given that you provided these details, this should be a new question over at ServerFault.